# Message: Undefined property: Todo::$uri

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter.

I get an error when I try to get the parameter in the url

```
<?php

class Todo extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();



}

public function index(){
$this->load->view('index.php');

}
public function blog(){
$this->load->view('arsiv');

}
public function test($param){
    $this->load->view('test');
    $a =  $this->uri->segment(2);


}
}
```

when i try to go : http://localhost/cod/index.php/todo/test/123

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Todo::$uri
>   Filename: controllers/Todo.php
>   Line Number: 21
>   Backtrace:
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cod/application/controllers/Todo.php
>   Line: 21
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cod/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to a member function segment() on null
>   Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cod/application/controllers/Todo.php
>   Line Number: 21
>   Backtrace:
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cod/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Comment: Hi @mehmtee10, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question needs to be edited. To improve you question quality, I invite you to read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the uri class is loaded automatically, so i'm not sure how you are getting this error given that you've extended ci_controller. this is the *exact* code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the URL helper is enabled in your config function

try to use $this->uri->get_segment(1);

Try to use

```
$CI =& get_instance(); 
$this->CI->uri->segment('2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

codigniter autoload.php file in config folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Url : http://localhost/laravel/users/abc
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(2);
Result : abc
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

you have to load helper in codigniter autoload.php file in config folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```